# creating a reusable library in XCode 3.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do I create a reusable library/module in XCode 3.2? What I want to do is create a bunch of classes that provide certain functionality compile them into some kind of library, add such a library to an existing xcode project and use the classes in it.
I come from .NET world so what I want to do is basically to create an equivalent of 'assembly' and  then reference it somehow in my XCode project.
I am developing for iOS btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a target called static library you will get the equivalent of an assembly, just put all the sources in the target and decide what headers should be published and what should be hidden to the user of your library.

Comment: thanks, for the answer, but what is the difference between a framework Greg mentioned and a static library?

Comment: I think i know the basic difference - framework can contain static/dynamic libraries and other resourcers (nibs etc)

Comment: it sounded as if you only needed a lib (KISS)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is create a 'framework'.

This page has some useful information.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html